# Use plain Javascript object as Ember model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is it possible to use a plain JS object (say literal object) as model in EmberJS ?

All the examples that I see in the documentation use Ember.Object (or datastore)

I assume I might not get things like observable, etc using plain JS. But is it at least supported ?

Answer (score 1):

This will not work reliably. A template such as

```
{{model.prop}}
```

operates by putting an observer on `'model.prop'`. This might work in some cases, but not in others, or you may get weird Ember messages.

Of all the aspects of Ember, the most basic is the Ember object model. Essentially, the entire framework is based on this model and using it to manage objects and retrieve and set properties. Once you've bought into Ember, you've bought into using this object model, which is based on old-fashioned classic inheritance.

A common case where your issue comes up is that a server API returns a plain old JS object as the value of a model property. You then want to dig around inside that object, or display its properties in templates. In such cases, it is probably best to either convert the object to an Ember Object (you can do this with transforms; google and you will find people doing this); or, use embedded models, which is not trivial to do, and may require server-side changes (such as including an ID in the embedded models, although you could theoretically add one yourself in the adapter). The latter is what I have done and the end result was to pretty much maintain my sanity.

Comment: Thanks...but in my current app, I use my server plain JSON response as return for my model hook (inside my route class) and it works, even though I never do explicit Ember.Object conversion...So is that done by Ember automatically ?